# How to tell gcc show me the list of optimization flags you used

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, g++

I have read the `gcc` [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for optimization options. They do not have examples.

One tedious method is to use [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/r88dM4) and try so many options and see which option works for a specific optimization flag.

I have written the following trivial code:

```
#include <cmath>

double calculate(double x)
{
    int y=x+sin(x);
    return exp(x)+exp(-x);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    return ceil(calculate(argc));
}
```

and I compiled it with

```
g++ -Q -v -O3 main.cpp
```

which prints all enabled optimization flag for me and not the used option flags. I also need to know the optimization flags for a specific function excluding the optimizations used for the libraries.

How is it possible for me to get the list of optimization flags used for compilation of `calculate` function?

Comment: why not to write a make file, and define the different build target for optimized and non-optimized  with the dedicated definition? For example, _ENABLE_OPTIMIZATION_.

Comment: @ravin.wang, How do you specify optimization flags only for a single function?

Comment: Most compilers, like gcc, do not specify optimization for a single function. Typically, an entire project is compiled with a desired optimization level.

Comment: @atrak please see http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/cpp_22.html, you can use ```__OPTIMIZE__``` to check whether compiler optimization is enabled or not.

Comment: @ravin.wang, this is not what I am looking for. gcc with `-Q -v` already gives me what `__OPTIMIZE__` dose. Even with higher details. What I am looking for is that I want to know from [this list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) what optimizations have been used to remove `y` in the `calculate` function. So I need to know the only optimization flag items that are used in `calculate` function with effect.

Comment: There is no option like this. a) it would be hard to implement b) it is useless.       If you have a specific problem you want to solve you should ask about that, I assume you wrongly think this option would help you.

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of GCC have the `-fverbose-asm` option that dumps the optimisation options enabled in a comment in the assembly file that you can get by compiling with `-S` or `-save-temps`